# SQL uniqueness constraint when using wildcard values

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Consider the following table, which specifies fruit that is forbidden on given days of the week. `DayOfWeek` is nullable, where a NULL signifies that this type of fruit is forbidden on *all* days of the week.

```
Fruit        DayOfWeek
----------------------
Kiwi         NULL
Apples       Monday
Strawberries Monday
Oranges      Tuesday
Bananas      Wednesday
Pineapple    Thursday
```

Is it possible to implement a constraint on this table that prevents me from inserting the values `(Kiwi, Monday)`, since Kiwis are already banned on Mondays (and every other day) by the existing `(Kiwi, NULL)` row.

Preferably this should be implemented *without the use of triggers*.

Comment: This is not an uniqueness constraint, it's just a business rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with others that I probably would aim for a different model than the one you've shown, but if you're sold on it, then the following seems to do what you want:

```
create table dbo.Weekdays (
    DayOfWeek varchar(10) not null,
    constraint PK_Weekdays PRIMARY KEY (DayOfWeek)
)
go
create table dbo.Exclusions (
    Fruit varchar(20) not null,
    DayOfWeek varchar(10) null,
    /* PK? */
    constraint FK_Exclusions FOREIGN KEY (DayOfWeek) references Weekdays (DayOfWeek)
)
```

Not sure what the PK is for the Exclusions table should be, not obvious from what you've shown, but it's intended to be your table. We need to introduce the `Weekdays` table to make the later view work*. Now populate it:

```
insert into dbo.Weekdays (DayOfWeek)
select 'Monday' union all
select 'Tuesday' union all
select 'Wednesday' union all
select 'Thursday' union all
select 'Friday' union all
select 'Saturday' union all
select 'Sunday'
```

And your sample data:

```
insert into dbo.Exclusions (Fruit,DayOfWeek)
select 'Kiwi',NULL union all
select 'Apples','Monday' union all
select 'Strawberries','Monday' union all
select 'Oranges','Tuesday' union all
select 'Bananas','Wednesday' union all
select 'Pineapple','Thursday'
```

Now we create the view to implement your constraint:

```
create view dbo.Exclusions_NullExpanded
with schemabinding
as
    select
        e.Fruit,
        wd.DayOfWeek
    from
        dbo.Exclusions e
            inner join
        dbo.Weekdays wd
            on
                e.DayOfWeek = wd.DayOfWeek or
                e.DayOfWeek is null
go
create unique clustered index IX_Exclusions_NoDups on dbo.Exclusions_NullExpanded (Fruit,DayOfWeek)
```

And, if we try to insert the row you don't want us to:

```
insert into dbo.Exclusions (Fruit,DayOfWeek)
select 'Kiwi','Monday'
```

We get:

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Exclusions_NullExpanded' with unique index 'IX_Exclusions_NoDups'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

*I initially tried to do this without introducing the `Weekdays` table, and have it appear inline in the view definition, as a subselect of literal rows. But you can't create the index that enforces the constraint we want on such a view.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a really good justification you shouldn't change the meaning of NULL. Null reflects a value is unknown so I would read this as We don't know what day of the week kiwi's are banned. You would then change your logic to store a record for each day of the week that Kiwi is banned on.

What if you need to write a query which says give me all forbidden fruit for monday. You need to write your query as

`select * from BadFruit where DayOfWeek='Monday' || DayOfWeek is null`

A more efficent and easier to understand query would eliminate the or clause.

Answer (score 1):

I am personally not fond of the idea of NULL mean all, but changing this to include a row for each day when NULL is probably out of scope.

If a trigger is not an option, I would look at a CHECK CONSTRAINT and setting up a function that tests the condition you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Can a CHECK CONSTRAINT validate conditions across all rows? I was kind of under the impression that a CHECK CONSTRAINT could only evaluate its logic based on the data columns within the individual row.

Comment: If the function you are calling from the constraint evaluates the table, you can do this. My preference would still be a TRIGGER on input, as it does not muddy the waters, so I probably should have jsut stated that and let it be.

Answer (score -1):

Try this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/SettingaUniqueConstraint.htm

For MySQL you can set unique contraints.

Comment: Unique won't work here, as KIWI, NULL and KIWI, Monday (invalid per OP) are both acceptable with a UNIQUE.